# Make Taskbar not semi-transparent

Tags: windows-8

Is there a way to make Windows not semi-translucent? Is there is a setting to change just this option, but save everything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently (at this moment in time), this is as close as you can get I'm afraid. I don't think you can do exactly what you want, it's either change the entire theme or leave the entire theme.

> Go to c:\windows\resources\themes\
>   Copy your .theme file someplace else
>   Under the key [VisualStyles] change the pointer to Aero.msstyles
>   to point to AeroLite.msstyles
>   Double click your .theme file

[Source](http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1102101-how-do-disable-transparency-in-windows-8s-taskbar/)

Comment: That doesn't answers my question, nor the so called duplicate.

Comment: @PetrAbdulin - can you explain why it doesn't answer it please or why this question is different to the duplicated cited?

Comment: The question clearly marks `just this option`, however solution provided changes not only that. It is noted in answer for "duplicate" question: *The downside of this approach is that the Aero lite theme looks different from the normal Windows 8 Aero theme.*

Comment: @PetrAbdulin I see. I'm not saying I agree/disagree with the closing vote but I would read the answer is no, not at this time and the cited post is your current best bet.

Comment: thanks, you should change the answer then, I'll mark it as an answer.